# Function losing context inside of Promise.all(reduce(acc, item) => {})) function

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, promise, reduce

I have a function

```
const integration = async (event) => {
    const user = await authenticateUser({
        email,
        password,
    })
    const authentication = path(['idToken', 'jwtToken'], user)

    return Promise.all(reduce(async (prevEvent, endpointId) => {
        const endpointDesc = endpoints[endpointId]

        let apiEvent = endpointDesc.actionEvent
        apiEvent.authentication = authentication

        if (endpointDesc.parameters.length > 0) {
            apiEvent = reduce((eventAcc, param) => {
                const prevPayload = eventAcc.payload
                const newPayload = { prevPayload, [param]: prevEvent.body[param] }
                return { ...apiEvent, payload: newPayload }
            }, apiEvent, apiEvent.parameters)
        }

        const lambdaParams = {
            FunctionName: apiFunctionArn,
            Payload: apiEvent,
        }

        const lambdaRes = await lambda.invoke(lambdaParams).promise()
        return lambdaRes
    }, Promise.resolve(), event.endpointId))
}
```

error from it is `undefined is not a function`

`lambda.invoke` is the piece of code causing errors

`lambda` object comes from `const lambda = new AWS.Lambda()` (`aws-sdk`)

`lambda.invoke`, before line with `return Promise.all(reduce(async (prevEvent, endpointId) => {` is working as it should work

I already tried things like lambda.invoke.bind(lambda) etc. but to be honest last times i totally forget object oriented javascript :X

if that's meaningful, I use `reduce` from `ramda`

Thanks from advance!

Comment: Why are you calling `Promise.all()` on the returned value from `reduce()`?  `reduce()` returns a single item (it's used to reduce a list to a single item).  Also, I don't see anywhere in the ramda doc that `reduce()` knows anything about the promises that async functions return.  It looks to me like you have an asynchronous issue with your `reduce()` callback and the `await` inside it.

Comment: removinig `Promise.all()` worked. thanks